# Как распарсить дату и время создания твита?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, twitter-api

По запросу `statuses/user_timeline` Twitter API помимо прочего возвращает поле `created_at` в формате:

> ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +0000 yyyy

Qt таковой формат "из коробки" не поддерживает. Возможно ли каким-нибудь образом корректно распарсить и наполнить данными объект `QDateTime` (разумеется, с учётом локального часового пояса), не прибегая при этом к помощи регулярного выражения?

"+0000" никогда не меняется, так как Твиттер возвращает время в UTC.

`QDateTime::fromString()` не подходит, т.к. пытается парсить входную строку, опираясь на текущую локаль, тогда как Твиттер краткие наименования месяцев, недель и т.п. всегда возвращает на латинице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил пока следующим образом:

```
QLocale locale(QLocale::English, QLocale::system().country());

QDateTime dt
    = locale.toDateTime(date_time_str
        , QStringLiteral("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +0000 yyyy"));

dt.setTimeZone(QTimeZone(0));
```